# What to do if Galaxy S2 firmware upgrade failed and the phone is not working at all?

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, device-firmware, system-error

I was upgrading my Galaxy S2 from Gingerbread 2.2.3 to Jelly Bean 4.1.2. In the middle of the process the USB cable just got disconnected and I only see a picture of mobile connected to a PC and a warning symbol in the center. I have tried hard-resetting it but its not working.